# Adding numbers to TFS Work Item Charts

Tags: charts, azure-devops, agile, tfs-workitem, issue-tracking

Is there a way to insert numbers to the Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online) Flow Chart for Work Items like the following excel report?

Similar to what I can do:
https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/TNBlogsFS/BlogFileStorage/blogs_msdn/bharry/WindowsLiveWriter/AnotheruseforTFSWorkItemTracking_6DA1/image%7B0%7D%5B18%5D.png

What I need to do:
https://agilebackblog.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/tfs_3.png

Comment: Please do not use naked links. Refer to my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this can't be achieved for now. There is no related configuration of the chart in web portal. However, you can view the numbers of the chart for every day when you try to move the mouse to the corresponding locations. It seems the numbers are hidden by default.

If you really need this feature, you can add a feature request in [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services). TFS Administrator will kindly review your suggestion.